Does Twilio Conversations store the media associated with WhatsApp messages
WhatsApp Cloud API deletes messages and media after 30 days:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/overview/data-privacy-and-security/
Does the Twilio Conversations API store the media separately from Twilio so that you can keep the media until you delete the messages within the Conversations API?
I cant find any documentation beyond requesting temporary urls for media!

Conversations messages are stored indefinitely until you delete them. This includes media messages.

Have you found anything in the docs to support this? This certainly stacks up against the fact they charge for this

I did not find it in any public documentation, but pretty sure it's like that. After all, I was on the team that implemented it.
